# Hibernate - NullPointerException when accessing a child element of one-to-many association

Tags: java, hibernate

There is a Java SE project with Hibernate ORM. I feel that the problem is trivial, but need some help.

There is a code snippet:

```
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session s = factory.openSession();

    int id = 1;

    ExperimentSetResult experimentSetResult = (ExperimentSetResult)s.get(ExperimentSetResult.class, id);

    System.out.println("size: " + experimentSetResult.getExperimentResults().size());
    System.out.println("id[0]: " + experimentSetResult.getExperimentResults().get(0).getId());
```

I get a NullPointerException for the last string of code (when accessing the 0-th element of a collection associated with an object loaded recently).

There are the hbm files snippets:

ExperimentResult.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="rmocommon.driverreaction.ExperimentResult" table="experiment_results">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one class="rmocommon.driverreaction.ExperimentSetResult" name="ExperimentSetResult" column="ExperimentSetResultId" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

ExperimentSetResult.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="rmocommon.driverreaction.ExperimentSetResult" table="experiment_set_results">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>

        <list name="ExperimentResults" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
            <key column="ExperimentSetResultId" not-null="true"/>
            <list-index column="Id"/>
            <one-to-many class="rmocommon.driverreaction.ExperimentResult"/>
        </list>    
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What's wrong with mapping or with my source code?

**UPDATE:**
Here is an output and a stack trace:

```
Hibernate: select experiment0_.id as id4_2_, experiment0_.StartedDate as StartedD2_4_2_, experiment0_.FinishedDate as Finished3_4_2_, experiment0_.DeviceOutput as DeviceOu4_4_2_, person1_.id as id0_0_, person1_.Login as Login0_0_, person1_.LastName as LastName0_0_, person1_.Patronymic as Patronymic0_0_, person1_.FirstName as FirstName0_0_, person1_.Age as Age0_0_, experiment2_.id as id1_1_, experiment2_.TestMode as TestMode1_1_, experiment2_.TransportType as Transpor3_1_1_, experiment2_.TransportStartSpeed as Transpor4_1_1_, experiment2_.RoadType as RoadType1_1_, experiment2_.RoadLength as RoadLength1_1_, experiment2_.DirectionLeft as Directio7_1_1_, experiment2_.RespondToFirstEffort as RespondT8_1_1_, experiment2_.SoundOnFirstEffort as SoundOnF9_1_1_, experiment2_.ScaleObjects as ScaleOb10_1_1_, experiment2_.ShowTransportSpeed as ShowTra11_1_1_, experiment2_.BarrierXMin as Barrier12_1_1_, experiment2_.BarrierXMax as Barrier13_1_1_, experiment2_.ReactionTime as Reactio14_1_1_, experiment2_.SoundOnBarrierAppearance as SoundOn15_1_1_, experiment2_.AllowedCheatCount as Allowed16_1_1_ from experiment_set_results experiment0_ left outer join persons person1_ on experiment0_.id=person1_.id left outer join experiment_set_settings experiment2_ on experiment0_.id=experiment2_.id where experiment0_.id=?
Hibernate: select experiment0_.ExperimentSetResultId as Experim11_4_1_, experiment0_.id as id1_, experiment0_.Id as Id1_, experiment0_.id as id2_0_, experiment0_.Distance as Distance2_0_, experiment0_.Crash as Crash2_0_, experiment0_.BrakingStarted as BrakingS4_2_0_, experiment0_.BrakingStartedTime as BrakingS5_2_0_, experiment0_.BrakingStartedDistance as BrakingS6_2_0_, experiment0_.BarrierX as BarrierX2_0_, experiment0_.Number as Number2_0_, experiment0_.Time as Time2_0_, experiment0_.Valid as Valid2_0_, experiment0_.ExperimentSetResultId as Experim11_2_0_ from experiment_results experiment0_ where experiment0_.ExperimentSetResultId=?
size: 6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hibernateTest.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:45)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of the NPE? Also include the output up to that point.

Comment: A stak trace would be helpful, check if experimentSetResult/getExpresult is null.. what is the size printed ?

Comment: I've just added a stack trace and got an idea that the size printed is wrong. There are actually 5 elements in an associated collection. I've tested them and... the first one is a null (WHY?) and the other 5 are the actual values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be that your mapping is wrong. Your list-index column definetly should not be ID.
If you really need the ordering, you better create a separate column for that, otherwise you will encounter problems.

Another thing I've noticed. You don't have to specify the inverse on the one-to-many relationship.

It's been a while I've seen hbm.xml files, can you use annotations? They are much easier to understand.

Comment: I think that you are right here, I've just got the same idea. Will try and return with the result.
Do you mind annotations are more appropriate? All the hibernate examples are written with hbm.xml

Comment: isn't the "inverse=true" for the list item enough?

Comment: annotations are just easier to grasp. They are more logical and modern.